# Can d3 draw pfam domain

Tags: tree, d3.js, protein-database

Just a quick question.
Can I use d3 to draw protein domains like the following?

[Image of a protein domain](http://www.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/rlw/text/bioinfo_tuto/images/graphic_view.jpg)

My plan is to attach these little protein domains to a tree, which would look awesome.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Quick answer: yes you can.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Cool! Do you happen to have a link with an example?

Comment: No. It looks like all you would need is a few bars and a circle/ellipse with some text in it though.

Comment: The usual spot for examples of all kinds https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery there are a few tree examples and some basic shape examples.

Comment: Suggest adding or linking the underlying data that constitutes a protein domain. Agree that it can be done.

Comment: Just to note: "Can D3 draw..." questions are like "Can a pencil draw..." questions. D3 renders SVG, and SVG can represent most vector images. If you are asking "Does D3 have a prebuilt component to draw protein domains?", then the answer is no.